# How to change key label of the custom android keyboard in java

Tags: java, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, android-input-method

I want to change the key label on my custom keyboard at run time, passing through java. I can't find any solution anywhere.

java file

```
public class MyKeyboardService extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    public final static int keyToChange = 257;


    KeyboardView kv;
    Intent intent;

    void updateInputView() {
        if (kv == null)
            return;
        Keyboard currentKeyboard = kv.getKeyboard();
        List<Keyboard.Key> keys = currentKeyboard.getKeys();
        keys.get(keyToChange).label = "Change Label";
        kv.invalidateKey(keyToChange);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {

        checkIfFirstRun();

        KeyboardView kv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.layout_keys);

        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setPreviewEnabled(false);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        updateInputView();


        return kv;
```

xml file

```
        <Key
            android:codes="257"
            android:keyWidth="60%p"/>
```

Now, I still get blank label on the key.
I want it to display "Change Label"

Comment: I don't think `onCreateInputView` is being called. I tried setting the label in a function that I manually call and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my keyboard. I wanted to have a button showing currency symbol most relevant to the user based on the user's locale.

So, the first hurdle in changing the label for a button is to identify the button. I added a static label to the key using which I identify the key in the code.

```
        <Key
            android:isRepeatable="true"
            android:keyLabel="@string/currencySymbol"
            android:keyWidth="25%p"/>
```

Next item of business was to change the label to my desire. In the view class, during initialisation (Object construction), I setup the label.

```
public NumberKeypadView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initialize(context);
}

public void initialize(Context context) {
    ...
    setCurrencySymbolBasedOnLocale(keyboard);
    ...
}

private void setCurrencySymbolBasedOnLocale(Keyboard keyboard) {
    for (Keyboard.Key key: keyboard.getKeys()) {
        if(key.label != null && key.label.toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.currencySymbol))) {
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        key.label = currency.getSymbol();
        key.text = currency.getSymbol();
        }
    }
}
```

And that is all.

Answer (score -1):

List<>.get() returns the key with the particular index, not the key with the particular code. For example, List<>.get(0) returns the first key.

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I did answer the question. Except for the other nicities.

Comment: Currently, it isn't very clear. Can you [edit] your answer to both format your code according to [editing help](/editing-help) and make it a clearer answer.